# How to measure time cost of multithreading program on Mac OS using C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos

I'm writing a multithreading program on Mac OS using C++, and I need to measure time cost of it.

Here I found some functions maybe useful to measure time:

1. clock(): for a multithreading program, it's not accurate.
2. time(): it can measure time but only have second precision.
3. gettimeofday(): I wrote a sample to test it, but got wrong time measurement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    timeval start, finish;
    gettimeofday(&start,NULL);

    sleep(10); //sleep for 10 sec

    gettimeofday(&finish,NULL);

    cout<<(finish.tv_usec-start.tv_usec)/1000.0<<"ms"<<endl;


    return 0;

}
```

The output is just few ms, I don't know why.

Does anyone know any other function to measure time on Mac OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the values is looping - when msecs gets to 1000, secs is incremented and msecs is set back to 0. When secs hits 60, mins is incremented and secs gets set back to 0.

If you are trying to measure time this way, you need to take all the fields bigger than your required minimum resolution into account.

Comment: Yes, I should add up tv_sec and tv_usec to get the right time measure. Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

`struct timeval` has two fields, `tv_sec` and `tv_usec`. You're ignoring `tv_sec`, thereby throwing away the most significant part of the time.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The mistake I made is to consider them as two different expressions using two units. Thus what I should do is to add up these two parts.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use the `<chrono>` functionality (that of course implies that you're using a c++11-enabled compiler).

Then you code might look like:

```
 #include <iostream>

 #include <chrono>
 #include <thread>

 using namespace std;
 using namespace std::chrono;

 int main()
 {
     auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

     std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s); //sleep for 10 sec

     cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count() << "ms\n";

     return 0;

 }
```

Note that I'm also using neat chrono literals to specify `10s`, which is c++14 feature. If it's not available, just use `seconds(10)` instead.

Note, however, that the output is not guaranteed to be "10000ms" as the OS is allowed to suspend the thread for longer - see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) (unistd one also doesn't guarantee that).

Cheers, 
   Rostislav.

Comment: Also, just as a side note - you're not using multithreading _yet_ - it's still a single-threaded application.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. The ouput should slightly longer than the sleep time. I'm now just testing the timer, and then use it to measure the time cost of my multithreading program.

Comment: As I tested just now, it cost the least time when I set the number of threads equal to the number of CPU cores. According to your experience, is that reasonable?

Comment: @Galaxy That sounds more reasonable than anything. Oversubscription is no joke - thread switches are cheap-ish, but not free so there's performance degradation _if_ all of the threads are busy.